# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object in react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am getting the error while using the DatePicker component from react-datepicker

**Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

<div>
<DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      >
</div>
```

Can somebody please suggest

Comment: That code isn't valid - can you please post the _actual_ code, not just an excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

If that is truly your code, you forgot to `return` something from your component. Additionally, don't forget the closing tag `/>` in your `<DatePicker />` component.

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

return <div>
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
    </div>
```